# How to make a copy of image without src?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, copy

I have to make a copy of given image after it's loaded. The problem is that the image is not usin static url and the image is different each time, it's generated with php on the server side. The link keeps the same every time. What I have to do is to make a copy of this already loaded image. How can I do that using HTML5 and canvas, or is there any other way to do that? I know that it can be done with canvas, but I need the src of the image. The problem is that it's not a static url, and when I do it, I get another picture instead of the loaded one. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make a copy"?

Comment: I want to display it twice on the same page. The problem is if I call the dynamic url twice it will generate 2 different images.

Comment: Missing something here, why isn't the php code simply delivering it twice?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it's a URL that delivers a random image, and apparently the `<img>` tag is coded with that as its "src".  If the `<img>` were simply cloned and added somewhere else in the DOM, the browser would fetch a new random image. (Presumably the image is delivered with caching disabled, etc.)

Comment: I'll try to explain it again:
The url is: "site.com/image"
<img src="site.com/image.php" alt="" /> for instance will display image with flowers.
<img src="site/image.php" alt="" /> will generate a car.

I want to display image with flowers twice. I can't use SRC because it will generate another image

Comment: Ah so it's not your Php code is the point I was missing.

Comment: When I right click and choose Copy Image from Chrome and Firefox and paste it to paint or PS, it makes the actual copy of the image. So it should be possible, but how?

Comment: @Ezio_ I added an answer some time ago. Is it not clear? You can simply draw the image into a canvas, and it'll look like another copy of the image on the page. It *won't* re-fetch the image from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a canvas; [it's pretty simple](http://jsfiddle.net/N9tup/):

```
<img src=http://placekitten.com/300/340 id=kitteh>
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c"), 
  kitteh = document.getElementById('kitteh'), 
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = kitteh.height; canvas.width = kitteh.width;
ctx.drawImage(kitteh, 0, 0);
```

Comment: +1 You have a correct answer based on the question and comments.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work for me the first time I'tried. This code works like a charm. Thanks Pointy!